# Do I have to monitor ClickHouse replica leader state?

Tags: clickhouse

According to official [docs](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/replicas/) of ClickHouse there's the request for monitoring that could inform me if something wrong with my replica.

```
SELECT
    database,
    table,
    is_leader,
    is_readonly,
    is_session_expired,
    future_parts,
    parts_to_check,
    columns_version,
    queue_size,
    inserts_in_queue,
    merges_in_queue,
    log_max_index,
    log_pointer,
    total_replicas,
    active_replicas
FROM system.replicas
WHERE
       is_readonly
    OR is_session_expired
    OR future_parts > 20
    OR parts_to_check > 10
    OR queue_size > 20
    OR inserts_in_queue > 10
    OR log_max_index - log_pointer > 10
    OR total_replicas < 2
    OR active_replicas < total_replicas
```

Have I additionaly monitoring leader state of my replica? What happens with replica if leader get down and there's no one node which could be leader instead (`can_become_leader: 0`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens with replica if leader get down and there's no one node which could be leader instead (can_become_leader: 0)?

Merges and mutations will stop. You will get the error "too many parts".

Comment: Other words there'll be increase of `future_parts` and `queue_size` metrics from the query above?

Comment: No. A leader creates tasks.

Comment: Hm.. so is there a way to monitor leader issues from query? The onliest way I see is cross-monitoring leader state in every node of cluster.

Comment: BTW, why do you need can_become_leader ?

Comment: I want to monitor ```is_leader```. My colleague ran into with problem when replica lost the leader and monitoring (from case above) didn't catch the moment.